# Trying to list all folders and subs in all drives to a file using cmd

Tags: cmd

I am new to this, please bear with me. I am try to list all folders in all drives to a list in a txt file. I get errors when the drive search reaches card reader drives and finds them empty. Tried 2>nul with no avail. Am I way off base with my syntax?  Thanks

```
rem ----------list all folders in all drives and copy to a file
for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q u r s t u v w x y z) do (if exist "%%a:\" 2>nul |dir "%%a:\" /ad /b /s >"c:\alldirs.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Next code should work:

```
echo off
rem ----------list all folders in all drives and copy to a file
(for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q u r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%a:\ dir %%a:\ /ad /b /s)>"c:\alldirs.txt" 2>nul
```

or breakdown that ugly line into multiple lines:

```
(for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q u r s t u v w x y z) do (
     if exist %%a:\ (
          dir %%a:\ /ad /b /s
     )))>"c:\alldirs.txt" 2>nul
```

Comment: Hi Josefz. It does work but hangs on drive error when it checks the empty sd reader. Any thoughts?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using  vol. This worked

```
for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do vol %%a: 2>nul |find "Volume" >nul && dir "%%a:\" /ad /b /s >>c:\alldirs.txt
```